# How can I implement a JavaScript that submit this form according to the clicket button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have the following problem that I can't solve:

I have this form into an HTML table:

```
<th width = "8.33%">
    <form id="actionButton" action="salwf.do?serv=1" method="post">
        <button name="accept" value="Accept" type="submit" class="acceptButton">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
        <button name="cancel" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="cancelButton">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
        <button name="sap" value="SAP" type="submit" class="sapButton">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>
        <input id="testId" name="test" type="hidden">
    </form>
</th>
```

As you can see this form contains three jQuery button elements and an hidden input tag.

I need to create a JavaScript that do the following operations: when the user click on one of the previous three buttons it take the value of the clicked button (**Accept** or **Cancel** or **SAP**) and submit it (in a POST request).

Can I do something like this using JavaScript? How can I implement it?

Comment: Have you written any JavaScript to try to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need it? Clicked button will be available in POST parameters anyway along with its value.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript? The form *already does that*! (And those are HTML buttons, not jQuery buttons).

Comment: a `<form>` inside `<th>`..? Your table's heading are `<form>`'s.? strange...

Comment: @Quentin judging the the `jquery-ui` tag he probably means this [buttons](http://jqueryui.com/button/)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a Javascript that do the following operations: when
>   the user click on one of the previous 3 buttons it take the value of
>   the clicked button (Accept or Cancel or SAP) and submit it (in a POST
>   request).

The value is submiited along with the request by itself. You have different `name`s, so check the presence of that `name` while processing your form request in post parameters.

```
Accept:Accept
Cancel:Cancel
SAP:SAP
```

Alternatively, what you can do is, to give your buttons different `id` but same `name`.

```
<button id="accept" name="ctrl" value="Accept" type="submit" class="acceptButton">ACCEPT</button>
<button id="cancel" name="ctrl" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="cancelButton">CANCEL</button>
<button id="sap" name="ctrl" value="SAP" type="submit" class="sapButton">SAP</button>
```

Then you can check the form request which will contain your value with the same key:

```
ctrl:Accept
ctrl:Cancel
ctrl:SAP
```

If you have different names, you will have a different key for every button.