# Why this Javascript form submission script don't work?

Tags: javascript

I am very new in JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I have this form:

```
<form id="actionButton" action="salwf.do?serv=1" method="post">
    <button id="accept" name="ctrl" value="Accept" type="submit" class="acceptButton" onclick="sottometti(this)">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button id="cancel" name="ctrl" value="Cancel" type="submit" class="cancelButton" onclick="sottometti(this)">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button id="sap" name="ctrl" value="SAP" type="submit" class="sapButton" onclick="sottometti(this)">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>

    <input id="testId" name="test" type="hidden">
</form>
```

As you can see this form contains 3 different button. Clicking on one of this button it is performed the **sottometti(this)** Javascript script, that have the following code:

```
function sottometti(obj){
    //document.getElementById('testId').value = obj.value;
    document.getElementById('testId').value = obj.value[id]
    document.getElementById('actionButton').submit()
}
```

This script should submit the previous form (the id of the clicked button) but it don't work. Why?

I think that it is trying to retrieve an **actionButton** that is not present in my form code.

Can you help me to make it work?

Comment: Do you want the value of the clicked button or the id to be put into the hidden field?

Comment: Why are you [still](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231254/how-can-i-implement-a-javascript-that-submit-this-form-according-to-the-clicket) messing about with JavaScript? Just give the buttons the name `test` instead of copying their values to a hidden input.

Comment: `obj.value[id]` is wrong (what does `id` even refer to here?), `obj.value` is correct. However, I believe your form will be submitted twice, since you submit it in code *and* the buttons are submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

replace `obj.value[id]` with `obj.id`.

Comment: Although this'll stop any javascript errors, im not sure the OP didnt want the `value` rather than the `id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative:

```
<form id="actionButton" action="salwf.do?serv=1" method="post">
    <button name="ctrl" value="accept" type="submit" class="acceptButton">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button name="ctrl" value="cancel" type="submit" class="cancelButton">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button name="ctrl" value="sap" type="submit" class="sapButton">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>
</form>
```

I have basically just removed all the JavaScript and the hidden input.

Now, on the server side, test it by simply outputting the value of the `ctrl` POST variable.

You should clearly see `accept`, `cancel` or `sap` according to the button that the user clicked. No JavaScript required, it's built-in, default functionality :)

Comment: Why are you assuming PHP? Judging by the file extension you'd be safe assuming [java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973505/which-programming-language-has-extension-do)

Comment: @Jamiec Good point. I wasn't paying that close attention. The point still stands, however: only the button you clicked will have its value sent to the server.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Its just the whole need for PHP in an answer nothing to do with PHP is a bit hard to swallow (Much better post-edit)

Comment: @Jamiec The lack of a server-side tag didn't help me ;) But I've edited my answer to be more agnostic.